# Is there a way to change a "skip" to "leave open"?

Tags: discussion, review-queue

I recently voted "skip" on a close vote review, since the question didn't look very good to me but I thought it could be salvaged (but wasn't sure how to do it myself).

I've now read an answer on that question that has convinced me it was good enough to start with.

Is there a way to change my vote? I think no, since googling has only given me info about the difference in the options (best I found was [this](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10356/how-to-vote-to-leave-open-without-going-through-every-question-on-the-close-qu?rq=1), which is basically "leave a comment and hope for the best", and also ignores that [voting "leave open" can get a question out of the close vote queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139834/what-exactly-happens-with-the-button-leave-open-previously-do-not-close)), but I hope yes, because I'd like to vote to keep the question open now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that if review hasn't yet completed by others.

First, go to your [review history](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/review/close/history) and check "show skipped reviews" box at the bottom right of this page [as explained here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234909/165773).

After that, find the title of question you skipped and click the link denoted by, well, word "Skip".

This will bring you to the review page of this question and over there, you will be able to pick Leave Open or Close (that is, unless review was already completed by other users).